# pygame sprites move in constant line

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying (badly) to write a very succinct program in pygame like Pong, but I seem to be stuck trying to move my paddles vertically. Moreover, while they do move... they only move in constant line.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vApnU.jpg)

```
#python code
import pygame, sys

#Screen Width/Height
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

#Background Image
background_image = pygame.image.load("tennis.jpg").convert()
screen.blit(background_image, [0,0])

#Frame Rate
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Paddles
paddle_player1 = pygame.Rect(5,50,5,60)
paddle_player2 = pygame.Rect(790,50,5,60)

#Process Player Input
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

       player1_up = pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w] 
       player1_down = pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_s]

       player2_up = pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]
       player2_down = pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_DOWN]

#Updating Game State Logic
        if player1_up:
            paddle_player1.y += -50
        if player1_down:
            paddle_player1.y += 50
        if player2_up:
            paddle_player2.y += -50
        if player2_down:
            paddle_player2.y += 50

        if paddle_player1.y < 0:
            paddle_player1.y = 0
        if paddle_player2.y < 0:
            paddle_player2.y = 0

    if paddle_player1.y > screen.get_height() - paddle_player1.height:
        paddle_player1.y = screen.get_height() - paddle_player1.height
    if paddle_player2.y > screen.get_height() - paddle_player2.height:
        paddle_player2.y = screen.get_height() - paddle_player2.height

#Rendering
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0), paddle_player1)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0), paddle_player2)


   clock.tick(50)
   pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: I'm not a Pygame user, but I would imagine that you need to blit your background image *inside* the loop, to overwrite the previous positions of the paddles.

Comment: this is no pygame spirit , this is ordinary drawing of a rect , .

Answer (score 0):

You need to call you blit inside your game loop, like so:

```
while True:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         pygame.quit()
         sys.exit()

      player1_up = pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w] 
      player1_down = pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_s]

      player2_up = pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]
      player2_down = pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_DOWN]

  #Updating Game State Logic
      if player1_up:
         paddle_player1.y += -50
      if player1_down:
         paddle_player1.y += 50
     if player2_up:
         paddle_player2.y += -50
     if player2_down:
         paddle_player2.y += 50

     if paddle_player1.y < 0:
         paddle_player1.y = 0
     if paddle_player2.y < 0:
         paddle_player2.y = 0


  if paddle_player1.y > screen.get_height() - paddle_player1.height:
     paddle_player1.y = screen.get_height() - paddle_player1.height
  if paddle_player2.y > screen.get_height() - paddle_player2.height:
     paddle_player2.y = screen.get_height() - paddle_player2.height

  screen.blit(background_image, [0,0]) #move your blit here

  pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0), paddle_player1)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0), paddle_player2)
```

Comment: Thank-you :) I was working on the code for most of yesterday... and all I needed was to change a small line - haha!